# How old is Q from Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-q

Based on when the last child was born in the Continuum, we know that he's at least a millennia old. How old is he?

Following the death of Quinn, a massive Q Civil War broke out, as the forces of the status quo resisted the calls for change in the Continuum, by a faction led by Q himself. Seeking to end the conflict, Q devised a plan to mate with Kathryn Janeway, the captain of Voyager, in order to create a new Q/Human hybrid – a new breed of Q that would help bring an end to the civil war. Janeway, however, flatly refused.

Q then proposed mating with his old girlfriend (instead of with Janeway) and she agreed. The new child, nicknamed Junior, became the first child born in the Continuum for millennia, and his presence brought an end to the civil war. (VOY: "The Q and the Grey")

We know from this that 'the Q' can mate and do reproduce, so Q was in fact 'born'. He jumps back and forth along the timeline from the beginning of life on earth to the far distant future so that's no real help to pin down an actual age. Is he really just a 'child' by continuum standards, à la Trelane (TOS: "The Squire of Gothos") or as old as the ages?

How old is he really?

-edit

Some try to claim that all Q suddenly came into existence at the same instant 'forever ago', therefore this question is held as redundant and without merit. The 'forever before and after' Q position is generally rationalized because the Q are immortal, exceedingly powerful and can time travel. Just because a being can have breakfast in 2375 on a starship, hangout on earth for lunch watching people trying to learn flint-knapping in 15,000 BC (after misplacing an asteroid belt), then jump forward to 15,000 AD for dinner while watching people trying to learn flint-knapping doesn't mean they have always been.

Such a position is not only tenuously founded but ignores the contrary facts and evidence that Q have been born in the past and born in 'the present'.

Per Memory Alpha:
"Based on descriptions by numerous Q, including the Q later known as Quinn, as well as Amanda Rogers (the child of two Q in Human form), the Q Continuum is a highly ordered society, but is also the result of eons of evolutionary stagnation." 
http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Q_Continuum

This alone admits that the Q are in fact the result of evolution. Because of this current state of 'evolutionary stagnation', Q even admits to Riker during his temptation (TNG 1X10 "Hide and Q"), that humans could become the Q's equal in the distant future. Also because of this 'evolutionary stagnation', Junior's conception caused quite a stir. It hadn't been done in quite some time...

All this side issue and Continuum lore being interesting an all still doesn't address the base question posed; How old is Q (John de Lancie)? Has there ever been any hint or comments relating to HIS age?

-further addition-

de Lancie himself discusses that the 'possible' creative force behind the 'Q' character was very likely the 'Trelane' character from TOS; who by the end of the episode was found to actually be a child from an ultra advanced/evolved species. Many believe that Trelane was in fact a 'Q' though he needed to use a hidden power source for much of his antics.

Comment: How old is an ageless, almost all-powerful entity that time travels?  As old or young as he wants to be!

Comment: We know that members of the Q-Species _can_ be born. That does not mean that the specific individual Q (played by John de Lancie) _was_ born.

Comment: Q and Q have a conversation where they reference the beginning of the 'new era'. The clear implication is that all of the Q ascended simultaneously. Presumably he and the other Q were the last corporeal generation

Comment: @Einer -Are you implying that some Q are born and some Q are 'created'?

Comment: @Richard -That episode, pray tell?

Comment: @Morgan No, I am implying that some Q are born and about other Q... we don't know how they came into existence. Just knowing that a property P applies to _some_ x does not imply that P applies to _all_ x. Most Qs may have existed forever. Or some of them. We just don't know.

Comment: @Einer -Guinan's comments about Q and Q's comments to Riker about the Q when he attempted to entice him strongly indicates that the Q are just highly evolved beings, not beings with no beginning. Just because they are immortal now doesn't mean that they are from forever past to forever future. They obviously had a 'beginning' point and possibly not immortal at their beginning.

Comment: @Morgan - Q2 was the product of an unheard-of mating between ascended Q's

Comment: Death wish talks about the new era.

Comment: @Richard -That question and related commentary revolve around where did 'The Q' come from. I'm asking how old is 'Q' (John de Lancie)?

Comment: @Richard -Possible dup? Did you even read that question and answers? Not even close to answering my question. I've come to expect more from you...

Comment: If Richard is right and every individual Q (except for Junior) are as old as the species, than the answer to this question is the answer to the question on how old the species is. That would render this into a duplicate. Otherwise I don't see how your question is answered in the linked question.

Comment: @einer - the clear implication of Q's monologue in "death wish" is that all Q became immortal simultaneously. Which makes this question a dupe. Moreover, even if it wasn't simultaneous, does it makea vast difference if Q is 5000030 years old or just 5000000?

Comment: @Richard -Per Memory Alpha synopsis of that episode; Q intends to leave Voyager with Quinn but Quinn insists that Janeway grant him asylum. As the pair of Q quarrel over the plea Quinn tries to escape from Q and dangerously transports Voyager to the time of the Big Bang (Q is scared by the thought of Voyager's crewmembers being responsible for humanoid life which could include the Continuum) and then reduces the ship to subatomic proportions... Hmmm, the 'original' evolutionary beginning of 'The Q' could be disrupted simply by Voyager's presence at the big bang?

Comment: @Richard Nope, to me it's all the same! But I didn't raised the question so it's not me who is to decide if of some 30 years are of any relevance.

Comment: I always assumed they were a normal biological species like humans, but "ascended" into their powerful, timeless state. With this in mind, they could have retroactively made all mortal Q be *immortal* and *eternal* Q. There might be some timeline paradoxes in there, but they are outside of time. So they had a start, but it was in a different timeline that no longer exists and doesn't mean anything anymore.